# Why some upvotes give 5 and some upvotes give 10?

Tags: support, voting

Why some upvotes give 5 and some upvotes give 10 rep. points?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Upvotes on questions give 5 reputation.  Upvotes on answers give 10.

Answer (score 5):

A couple of references:

https://math.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/03/important-reputation-rule-changes/